# PySpark : regexp_extract 5 next words after a match

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset like this:

| column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- |
| First | a a a a b c d e f c d s |
| Second | d f g r b d s z e r a e |
| Thirs | d f g v c x w b c x s d f e |

I want to extract the 5 next words after the "b" value
to obtain this using regexp_extract :

| column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- |
| First | c d e f c |
| Second | d s z e r |
| Thirs | c x s d f |

Is it possible ? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
df.withColumn("column2", F.regexp_extract(F.col("column2"),"(?<=b )(\w\W){4}\w",0))
```

Output:

```
|column1|  column2|
+-------+---------+
|  First|c d e f c|
| Second|d s z e r|
|  Thirs|c x s d f|
+-------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex to extract the 5 next words after b:

```
pattern = "(?i)\\b(?:b\\W+)(\\w+\\W+\\w+\\W+\\w+\\W+\\w+\\W+\\w+)\\b"
df = df.withColumn("column2", regexp_extract(col("column2"), pattern, 1))
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Result:

```
+-------+---------+
|column1|column2  |
+-------+---------+
|First  |c d e f c|
|Second |d s z e r|
|Thirs  |c x s d f|
+-------+---------+
```